# NoSuchMethodError when using submitting form in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm currently working through [the tutorial](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/coding-actions.html) found on the Apache Struts website.

Currently, whenever I press submit on the form, or when I click the Bruce Philips hyperlink, I get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ognl.SimpleNode.isEvalChain(Lognl/OgnlContext;)Z
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.isEvalExpression(OgnlUtil.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:215)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:174)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:152)
        ....
```

I'm not too sure what the issue is either and I believe I've included everything the tutorial states. I've tried including the dependency in my `pom.xml`, but that makes no difference either.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Struts2PracticeSite</groupId>
  <artifactId>Struts2PracticeSite</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
    <build>
        <finalName>Struts2PracticeSite</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    
    
</project>
```

Any ideas on how I would fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have more than one `ognl-*.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: How would I check for that?

Comment: If you are deploying your application as a WAR file, open it with some zip utility (WinZip or so) and go to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Make sure you have only one `ognl-*.jar` file there. As an alternative, run `mvn clean` and redeploy and see if the error is gone. Sometimes I got stuck with similar errors and I found there were duplicated jars in my deployed WAR.

Comment: I just tried both solutions, and unfortunately it didn't make a difference. ognl-3.0.6.jar is the only ognl, and running maven clean before redeploying didn't work either.

Comment: Please include your entire pom. You're almost certainly mixing versions of libraries somewhere.

Comment: I've added the full POM to the original post.

Comment: Does the tutorial include war for deployment or zip with project sources?

Comment: @user1970873 You should remove the OGNL dependency; the S2 dependency will pull in the correct version. Other than that, there's nothing wrong w/ what I see so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found... Turns out my server version is too old to handle struts 2. I was previously using Geronimo version 2.0.2, and it now runs fine on GlassFish 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

struts2.3.1.1 allows **ognl3.0.2.jar + ognl3.0.2-source.jar + ognl3.0.1
at the same time**
. struts2.3.1.2 can only have ognl3.0.4, but remove other versions

**ognl3.0.4** is a must and can be the only ognl jar!

Comment: I'm using struts 2.3.8 though, and ognl 3.0.6 is acceptable for it apparently. I'll try using a different ognl version to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, using a different ognl version still makes no difference =/

Comment: where is you jar files ? Are you using user define library or or placing jar files directly in WEB-INF/lib. Amd also tell me which eclipse version you using .

Comment: Jar Files are in WEB-INF/lib. Version of Eclipse is 3.3.2.

Comment: Use eclipse version 3.7 indigo or higher Earlier version directly not support struts2.

Comment: @Arvind: And how Eclipse supports Struts2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dependencies you need

```xml
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
     <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
     <version>${struts2.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
     <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${struts2.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

there are also other dependencies but these are necessary for Struts2 Tiles application.

Comment: Those are already in my Web-INF/lib. I think the struts2-core dependency pulled them in.

Comment: I don't know what you have in the Web-INF/lib, post the list of jars.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ognl` as a dependency as this is already a transient dependency of `struts 2.3.8` itself and make sure if Eclipse properly deployed your applications, there are many problems with that.

Comment: ognl has been removed, still does not work. I'm compiling with maven as well, so I'm not sure if my eclipse has any impact on how it's being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

**Use these Jar Combinations for Struts 2 application**

[image]